# FreeBSD cli history for sh shell

Tags: shell, freebsd, command-history

During FreeBSD 11 Release installation I setup for my new user the standard shell "/bin/sh" as default. Is there a way to make history for this shell permanent that I can use history after reboot. Or do I have to switch to another shell like bash?

Additionally does sh support `ctrl+R` to search through history?

Comment: FreeBSD `sh` is not the Bourne shell, it is based on the Almquist shell, has been (mostly) POSIXified and has a few extensions.

Comment: use ``vipw`` to change user shell

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thx for clarifying, so this topic is not related to my question anyhow?

Comment: @user996142 you mentioned I should use `bash` or something else?

Comment: `sh` there uses the `editline` library. See `man editrc` for configuration.

Comment: You may use bash if you like ``readline``. But you also may use ``ksh`` or ``tcsh`` or even stay with ``sh`` and configure it with ``editline``

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I will read it out, that's new for me I had no Linux or Unix installed before where this function was not running out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

It is not whether `sh` supports searching through history and persistent history.  It is whether the editing library that it uses does.  The editing library is `libedit`.  Indeed it does support searching through history.  It does not support persistent history.

There is no key mapped to the next/previous search history actions by default.  But you can map one.

```
bind ^R ed-search-prev-history
```

This mapping usually goes in `$HOME/.editrc`.  You can make it general or specific to `sh`.

Tip: You type the pattern to search for *before* pressing the `ed-search-prev-history` key in `libedit`.  Not after.

## Further reading

- Luke Mewburn (2014). [editrc](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=editrc).  §5.  FreeBSD Manual.
- Luke Mewburn (2014). [editline](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=editline).  §3.  FreeBSD Manual.