# Setup cli history in FreeBSD 11

Tags: shell, freebsd, command-history

In `$HOME/.profile` the environment variable `ENV`is set to `$HOME/.shrc` and defined via `export ENV`. My shell `echo $0` is `-sh`.

In `$HOME/.shrc` I declared the variables HISTFILE and HISTSIZE:

```
HISTFILE=$HOME/.sh_history
HISTSIZE=500
export HISTFILE
export HISTSIZE
```

But after reboot there is no history available.

EDIT:

> HISTORY
>
> ```
>  A sh command, the Thompson   shell, appeared in Version 1 AT&T UNIX.  It
>  was superseded in Version 7 AT&T UNIX by the Bourne shell,   which inher-
>  ited the name sh.
>
>  This version of sh   was rewritten in 1989 under the BSD license after the
>  Bourne shell from AT&T System V Release 4 UNIX.
> ```
>
> AUTHORS
>
> ```
>  This version of sh   was originally written by Kenneth Almquist.
> ```

Comment: Given your question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375214/ and its answer, you need to be clearer about which shell you are using here.

Comment: @JdeBP, I will accept your answer after review. But this question is different  and your answer in the your given link is only about searching history, e.g. which comes out of the box in ubuntu stroking `ctrl+R`.

Comment: The question and answer there is also about persistent history.  I didn't talk about accepting answers.  I recommended being clearer about which shell you are using.  You have done nothing to make it clear *which shell you are using here*.

Comment: @JdeBP  "My shell `echo $0` is `-sh`." doesn't resolve which shell I'm using here?

Comment: No, of course not, given that one can arrange to invoke several shells in their POSIX conformant or Bourne-compatible modes by using that name.  Add to that the aforementioned question where you talk about possibly using an add-on shell instead of the one supplied with the operating system; and both https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375250/ and here where you talk about mechanisms that, as I told you in answer to your first question, the Almquist shell *does not have*.  You need to tell people *which shell you are using*.

Comment: @JdeBP, I don't know what else I can do to determine the shell. It's `/bin/sh` in FreeBSD 11, that is not a symbolic link and the output of  `echo $0` is `-sh`. The link you refer to is a complete different machine and the question is more general or lets say kinda independent from specific shell. So how to determine additional informations about the shell in this topic (I added some facts from man page)?

Comment: Hi, the problem is that `/bin/sh` is not really used as a login in shell under FreeBSD. `/bin/sh` is a absolute minimal shell for script execution and disaster recovery. So `sh` has just minimal features and no permanent history.  Usually you will use `/bin/tcsh` or install other shells for these kind of features.

Answer (score 1):

The root account uses tcsh by default, which takes the "history" alias/command; Whereas sh is the default for users unless otherwise specified. The actual binary for the history command for sh is:

```
/usr/bin/fc
```

with the `-l` flag, i.e. `fc -l`

Also look at `man history`

Comment: Thx for answer. I had to change my question, because I already read the man page and become confused. Because my original question is different. Please see my edits.

Comment: Why did you put `unset HISTFILE`
`unset HISTSIZE` in the ".shrc" file? also I would use ~/.profile

Comment: only to be sure there is nothing declare elsewhere. But I can comment  those lines, I think it doesn't mind.

Comment: Use `~/.profile` not `~/.shrc`. Quote: `# .profile - Bourne Shell startup script for login shells
#
# see also sh(1), environ(7).
#`

Comment: Where is the difference? `.shrc` should invoked each time sh is started, because it is defined in `.profile` as I wrote above. "The  user can set the ENV
     variable to some file by placing the following line in the file .profile
     in the home directory, substituting for .shrc the filename desired..."

Comment: Ah I didn't see that part after the change. You could try /etc/login.conf?